# R label sequence by changing factor values

Tags: r, dplyr, seq

I have the following data:

| Account | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-09-23 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-09-30 | 5 |
| 1 | 2021-10-30 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-12-29 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-01-31 | 8 |
| 1 | 2022-02-02 | 0 |

I need to find the minimum date of each individual transition.

```
group_by(Account, type) %>%
summarise(first_appearance = min(date))
```

returns

| Account | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-31 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-09-30 | 5 |
| 1 | 2022-01-31 | 8 |

How can I group by each SHIFT in type?

My initial thoughts are to generate some sort of sequence along the factors and concatenate to have a unique grouping variable, but how would this be done?

| Account | date | type | order | type_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-31 | 0 | A | 0A |
| 1 | 2021-09-23 | 0 | A | 0A |
| 1 | 2021-09-30 | 5 | A | 5A |
| 1 | 2021-10-30 | 0 | B | 0B |
| 1 | 2021-12-29 | 0 | B | 0B |
| 1 | 2022-01-31 | 8 | A | 8A |
| 1 | 2022-02-02 | 0 | C | 0C |

Desired output would be:

```
group_by(Account, type_order) %>%
summarise(first_appearance = min(date))
```

| Account | date | type | order | type_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-31 | 0 | A | 0A |
| 1 | 2021-09-30 | 5 | A | 5A |
| 1 | 2021-10-30 | 0 | B | 0B |
| 1 | 2022-01-31 | 8 | A | 8A |
| 1 | 2022-02-02 | 0 | C | 0C |

Comment: Is the expected output column correct i.e. the 'order' column

Comment: What do you mean by each shift in type? Your expected output is a bit unclear.

Comment: @akrun yes, I added in the desired output to make it clearer.

Comment: @JasonRichardson I am a bit confused by the occurrence of 'A' in desired output at row 5.  Can you please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use `rleid` from `data.table` to assign groups when there are differences in `type` from row to row.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  group_by(Account, grp = rleid(type), type, order) %>%
  summarise(first_appearance = min(date))
```

**Output**

```
  Account   grp  type order first_appearance
    <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>           
1       1     1     0 A     2021-08-31      
2       1     2     5 A     2021-09-30      
3       1     3     0 B     2021-10-30      
4       1     4     8 A     2022-01-31      
5       1     5     0 C     2022-02-02
```

Comment: THIS but "order" is the field I was trying to generate. Either way awesome to know this now.

Comment: @JasonRichardson I see - I hope this was helpful. If there's something we can modify to more accurately represent a solution for the above question, I'd be happy to edit. Just let me know.